# Regular Expression for Folder Path

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

If I have the following regular expression:

```
c:\\Users\\.*?\\AppData\\.*?\.exe
```

It will match:

```
C:\Users\jftuga\AppData\test.exe
C:\Users\jftuga\AppData\Local\test.exe
```

How can I modify the RE so that is only matches the first entry and not sub-directories as well?

I am using c# and .net framework 4 - with `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: Your pattern doesn't match either of your test strings.  The pattern starts with `c` (lowercase), but the strings start with `C` (uppercase)

Comment: It does. I updated the question and added RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a character class that looks for `\`:

```
c:\\Users\\.*?\\AppData\\[^\\]*?\.exe
```

[Play with it here](https://regex101.com/r/qZ0mZ6/1)

Comment: So in general, will the negation clause always go before what you are trying to match? Also, why should there not be a . in front of the *? It is because the Negation matches everything (by default) except for \

Comment: The whole `[^\\]*?` says match zero or more characters that are not back-slashes.  The reason you don't want a `.` in front of the `*?` is because a `.` matches any character, including back-slashes.  In my pattern, after the `AppData\\` part, there is nothing that will match a back-slash.  (also, does your filesystem allow for forward-slashes?)